# Custom Post Type Shows Only One of the Registered Taxonomies While Three Taxonomies are Registered

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a plugin like this code and as you can see I have registered 3 taxonomies `curriculum-levels` and `curriculum-types` and `curriculum-grades` like

```
register_taxonomy( 'curriculum-levels', array( 'curriculum-program' ), $args );
register_taxonomy( 'curriculum-types', array( 'curriculum-program' ), $args );
register_taxonomy( 'curriculum-grades', array( 'curriculum-program' ), $args );
```

and on custom post type I have

```
 $args = array(
  ...
  'taxonomies'  => array( 'curriculum-levels', 'curriculum-grades', 'curriculum-types'),
  ...
 );
```

but I am only getting the `curriculum-grades` in the admin menu!

[image]

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

```
flush_rewrite_rules( true );

function  cpt_curriculum_level_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Curriculum Levels',
        'singular_name'              => 'Curriculum Level',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Curriculum Levels',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Curriculum Levels',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent Curriculum Level',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Curriculum Level:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Curriculum Level Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add Curriculum New Level',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Curriculum Level',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Curriculum Level',
        'view_item'                  => 'View Curriculum Level',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Curriculum Levels with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Curriculum Levels',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Curriculum Level',
        'popular_items'              => 'Popular Curriculum Level',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Curriculum Levels',
        'not_found'                  => 'Not Found Curriculum Level',
        'no_terms'                   => 'No Curriculum Levels',
        'items_list'                 => 'Curriculum Levels list',
        'items_list_navigation'      => 'Curriculum Levels list navigation',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'levels', 'with_front' => true),
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,

    );
    register_taxonomy( 'curriculum-levels', array( 'curriculum-program' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', ' cpt_curriculum_level_taxonomy', 0 );

function cpt_curriculum_type_taxonomy() {

$labels = array(
        'name' => 'Curriculum Types',
        'singular_name' => 'Curriculum Type',
        'menu_name' => 'Curriculum Types',
        'all_items' => 'All Curriculum Types',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Curriculum Type',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Curriculum Type:',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Curriculum Type Name',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Curriculum Type',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Curriculum Type',
        'update_item' => 'Update Curriculum Type',
        'view_item' => 'View Curriculum Type',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Curriculum Types with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove Curriculum Types',
        'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from the most used Curriculum Type',
        'popular_items' => 'Popular Curriculum Type',
        'search_items' => 'Search Curriculum Types',
        'not_found' => 'Not Found Curriculum Types',
        'no_terms' => 'No Curriculum Types',
        'items_list' => 'Curriculum Types list',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Curriculum Types list navigation',
);
$args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'curriculums', 'with_front' => true),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,

);
register_taxonomy( 'curriculum-types', array( 'curriculum-program' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_curriculum_type_taxonomy()', 0 );

function cpt_curriculum_grade_taxonomy() {

$labels = array(
        'name' => 'Curriculum Grades',
        'singular_name' => 'Curriculum Grade',
        'menu_name' => 'Curriculum Grades',
        'all_items' => 'All Curriculum Grades',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Curriculum Grade',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Curriculum Grade:',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Curriculum Grade Name',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Curriculum Grade',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Curriculum Grade',
        'update_item' => 'Update Curriculum Grade',
        'view_item' => 'View Curriculum Grade',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Curriculum Grades with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove Curriculum Grades',
        'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from the most used Curriculum Grade',
        'popular_items' => 'Popular Curriculum Grade',
        'search_items' => 'Search Curriculum Grades',
        'not_found' => 'Not Found Curriculum Grades',
        'no_terms' => 'No Curriculum Grades',
        'items_list' => 'Curriculum Grades list',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Curriculum Grades list navigation',
);
$args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'grades', 'with_front' => true),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'curriculum-grades', array( 'curriculum-program' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_curriculum_grade_taxonomy', 0 );


function cpt_curriculum_program_cpt() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Curriculum Programs',
        'singular_name'         => 'Curriculum Program',
        'menu_name'             => 'Curriculum Programs',
        'name_admin_bar'        => 'Curriculum Program',
        'archives'              => 'Curriculum Program Archives',
        'attributes'            => 'Curriculum Program Attributes',
        'parent_item_colon'     => 'Parent Curriculum Program:',
        'all_items'             => 'All Curriculum Programs',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Add New Curriculum Program',
        'add_new'               => 'Add New Curriculum Program',
        'new_item'              => 'New Curriculum Program',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edit Curriculum Program',
        'update_item'           => 'Update Curriculum Program',
        'view_item'             => 'View Curriculum Program',
        'view_items'            => 'View Curriculum Program',
        'search_items'          => 'Search Curriculum Program',
        'not_found'             => 'Curriculum Program Not found',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'Curriculum Program Not found in Trash',
        'featured_image'        => 'Curriculum Program Featured Image',
        'set_featured_image'    => 'Set Curriculum Program Featured image',
        'remove_featured_image' => 'Remove Curriculum Program Featured image',
        'use_featured_image'    => 'Use as Featured image',
        'insert_into_item'      => 'Insert into Curriculum Program',
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => 'Uploaded to this Curriculum Program',
        'items_list'            => 'Curriculum Programs list',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Curriculum Programs list navigation',
        'filter_items_list'     => 'Filter Curriculum Programs list',
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => 'Curriculum Program',
        'description'           => 'Curriculum Program Post Type Description',
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title','editor','excerpt','thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'curriculum-levels', 'curriculum-grades', 'curriculum-types'),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => false,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'curriculum-program', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_curriculum_program_cpt', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"why this is happening and how I can fix this?"*

Because when you used the `init` hook, you have passed incorrect `calback function names`:

This:

```php
add_action( 'init', ' cpt_curriculum_level_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Should be this (without the space in the beginning!):

```php
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_curriculum_level_taxonomy');
```

And replace this one:

```php
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_curriculum_type_taxonomy()', 0 );
```

with this (without the parentheses!):

```php
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_curriculum_type_taxonomy');
```

And here's the result:

[image]